# Is it possible to use CXF webservice in Android?

Tags: android, web-services

I want to use the CXF webservice setup for web in my android program, is it possible to use the same webservice for both? The log msg is as follows. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

```
12-04 08:59:28.432: E/Trace(850): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-04 08:59:29.285: E/dalvikvm(850): Could not find class 'org.jida.mns.web.ws.connector.WSConnector', referenced from method com.example.list.MainActivity.onCreate
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.cdac.nms.web.ws.connector.WSConnector
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.example.list.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-04 08:59:29.332: E/AndroidRuntime(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for your specific case or the stacktrace. But as for using cxf to build your WS client in android, it should be possible.

See for example this project http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/ which is using CXF to build clients on android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.......... will u please tell me How to add an external java project to the the current android program?

Comment: When i run the ws client program in the link provided by you , at runtime i get the following error in logcat, if u can pls help me to resolve that.                                                                  12-04 11:11:27.452: E/Trace(1105): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: I hardly try so many months and found it is almost very difficult( I dont say it is impossible, may be some geniouses can do miracles) to directly use cxf webservice as in java. Since my webservice is a soapful webservice I,m now comfortable with the ksoap2 library